# I've never seen this partial differentiation notation before and it makes me doubt my conceptual understanding!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

This paper I am reading has strange notation I have never seen before. It has two potential functions $W$ and $\Phi$ and the partial derivatvies with w are represented normally.

$\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial y^2}$.

However, the partial derivatives for $\Phi$ are represented differently:

$\frac{\Phi}{\partial y}$ and $(\frac{^2\Phi}{\partial y^2})$

Is there any significance to this? I have always believed that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ was an operator. I feel like I must be fundamentally miss-understanding something conceptually because the second notation violently disagrees with my intuition. Furthermore, later in the paper the represent a relationship as follows,

$d(f(p,T)) = g(y,t)dt$

Where f is a function of pressure and temperature and g is a function of position and time. I guess this is saying that if we take tiny changes in f (but with respect to what?!?) it is equal to function g over tiny changes in time.

Ive never seen differentiation treated like this and I am very confused!

Here is a link to the article. The weird notation can be seen on pages 24 and 26: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/98JB00906

Comment: It's weird that they wrote the same thing several times over, but I can only surmise that the $\partial$ symbols got dropped, perhaps in the course of digitization. As for the differential notation, this is rather standard in areas like thermodynamics, it says that the instantaneous change in $f$ during whatever process it is that you are doing is given by $g$ times the instantaneous change in $t$. It's a bit confusing that  the variables in $f$ and $g$ aren't the same, though, presumably there is some implicit dependence of $T,p$ and $y$ with $t$.

Comment: Thanks for your response!